# sjPlot CSS not rendering in Knitr spin() Doc

Tags: r, knitr, sjplot

I am trying to integrate sjPlot's lmer html table into a knitr html document compiled with spin() but in rendering the css is lost. I am following instructions here: http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjt.lmer/.

Here is my code:

`#+ results='asis'
sjt.lmer(timeFE_r4, polyTime_r4, no.output = T)$knitr`

Any suggestions for settings? It will not render at all if results='asis' is not set.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to use `spin()`? Else, simply integrate following code line in your knitr-document: \`r sjt.lmer(timeFE_r4, polyTime_r4, no.output = T)$knitr\`, see http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjtbasics/

Comment: Thanks for the response, Daniel. I suppose I could, However, the file is quite code heavy and so `spin()` seems to be more appropriate.

Comment: @Daniel the link in the comment is corrupt. Nice packages btw

Comment: I finally moved the packages' websites to GitHub, together with pkgdown it is easy to manage the websites. You find the vignettes here: https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/ and the general website in the parent directory: https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/